# Correct way to import and export javascript function library (module redirect)

Tags: javascript

Consider the following file having multiple exports (a library of functions):

**lib.js:**

```
export const Funct1 = () => {
...
}

export const Funct2 = () => {
...
}

export const Funct3 = () => {
...
}
```

In other to work with shared code between environments, I need to build a intermediate file to import all the lib.js functions and make then available to new project as exports (module redirecting). Here is my code:

**MyLib.js**

```
export { default as functionlib } from "./src/helpers/lib";
```

Now I need to import the MyLib.js into my end code:

**App.js**

```
import { lib } from "../shared/MyLib.js"

...

// Later use the function
let a = lib.Funct1();
```

Under that syntax `lib` ends being `null` at my end code `App.js`.

These are variations I've used in `MyLib.js` and the result errors on App.js:

```
import { default as lib } from "../shared/MyLib.js" <--- ERROR: lib ends being null
```

or

```
import { * as lib } from "../shared/MyLib.js" <--- ERROR: unexpected token at *
```

How can I properly redirect all my functions inside `MyLib.js` to make available all the `lib` functions (without expliciting all the ``` lib`` functions inside ```MyLib`) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to do it "in a bulk mode" without expliciting all the
> library functions?

No, dynamically computed value cannot be statically exported: [ECMAScript 6 modules: the final syntax](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html):

> You may be wondering – why do we need named exports if we could simply default-export objects (like CommonJS)? The answer is that you can’t enforce a static structure via objects and lose all of the associated advantages (described in the next section).

---

You can either **Default export:**

```
//lib.js
const Funct1 = () => {
...
}

export default Funct1;
```

**Default import:**

```
import Funct1 from './lib.js'
import MyFunc from './lib.js'
import Whatever from './lib.js'
```

You can assign any name when importing, because it resolves to whatever the default export of `lib.js` is.

---

Or **Named export:**

```
//lib.js
export const Funct1 = () => {
...
}
```

**Named import**

```
import { Func1 } from './lib.js'
import { MyFunc } from './lib.js' //Doesn't work
import { Whatever } from './lib.js' //Doesn't work
```

In this case the import name must correspond with the export name since you're importing a specific thing by it's name.

### [More on the subject](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html)

---

## lib.js

```
export const Funct1 = () => {
...
}

export const Funct2 = () => {
...
}

export const Funct3 = () => {
...
}
```

## MyLib.js

```
export {
  Funct1,
  Funct2,
  Funct3,
} from "./src/helpers/lib";

//You can easily add more
export {
  Foo,
  Bar
} from "./src/helpers/fooBar";
```

## App.js

```
import * as MyLib from "../shared/MyLib.js"

// Usage
MyLib.Funct1()
MyLib.Foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your **MyLib.js**:

```
import * as lib from "./src/helpers/lib";

export default lib;
export * from "./src/helpers/lib";
```

Then in your **App.js**:

```
import lib from "../shared/MyLib.js";
// OR
import { Funct1 } from "../shared/MyLib.js";

console.log(lib.Funct1); // function Funct1() {}
console.log(Funct1); // function Funct1() {}
```

**Demo**: https://codesandbox.io/s/62jrp3k83k

Answer (score 0):

## ECMAScript modules example:

```js
/*
 * [package]/src/lib.mjs
 */
export function Func1() {
  // ...
}
export function Func2() {
  // ...
}
export function Func3() {
  // ...
}

/*
 * [package]/index.mjs
 */
export * from "./src/lib.mjs";

/*
 * App.mjs
 */
import { Func1, Func3 } from '[package]';
Func1();
Func3();
```

Answer (score -1):

## MyLib.js

```
import { Funct1, Funct2, Funct3 } from "./src/helpers/lib";

const MyLibs = {
  Funct1,
  Funct2,
  Funct3,
};

export default MyLibs;
```

## App.js

```
import MyLib from "../shared/MyLib.js"

// Usage
MyLib.Funct1()
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it "in a bulk mode" without expliciting all the library functions?

Comment: The last one is the "bulk" mode you can avoid to create an object with const and export directly the object that wraps the functions